# photo liked again when i back to it

Tags: javascript, php

when someone hit a heart icon to like a photo, then it browse other photos then back to that photo
it liked again, so, it will shows in the first images again in the "new liked photos" page

here is codes

```js
function Favorite(userid,postid,status){
    
   $.ajax({  
    url: '<?php echo site_url('Home/favorite'); ?>',
    type: "POST",
    data:{userid:userid,postid:postid,status:status}, 
       success:function(responce){
    if(status==1){
     
    $('#showlikes'+postid).html('<span data-post-likes="'+postid+'"> '+responce+' </span><strong>Likes</strong>');
    
    $('#changelike'+postid).html('<span  onclick="return Favorite('+userid+','+postid+',0);" class="like-post active"><span class="like-icon heart"><div class="heart-animation-1 heart"></div><div class="heart-animation-2 heart"></div></span></span>');
    //alert('Post added in your Favorite list.');
    
    } else {
     
    $('#showlikes'+postid).html('<span data-post-likes="'+postid+'"> '+responce+' </span><strong>Likes</strong>');
    
    $('#changelike'+postid).html('<span  onclick="return Favorite('+userid+','+postid+',1);" class="like-post "><span class="like-icon heart"><div class="heart-animation-1 heart"></div><div class="heart-animation-2 heart"></div></span></span>'); 
    //alert('Post remove in your Favorite list.');
    
    }
    
   }
   
  });

 }
```

```html
<div class="sb_network_holder"><a class="sb_network_button fa fa-heart" target="_blank" href="//weheartit.com/heart-it/new_entry?encoding=UTF-8&amp;hearting_method=heart_it_button&amp;image_url=<?php echo $image_urls; ?>&amp;popup=1&amp;source_url=https://www.****.com/details/<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" data-network="heart" style="display: block; left: 3px; top: 3px;"></a><a class="sb_network_button fa fa-twitter" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://www.****.com/details/<?php echo $value['id']; ?>&amp;text=<?php echo $value['description']; ?>" data-network="twitter" style="display: block; left: 3px; top: 3px;"></a><a class="sb_network_button fa fa-pinterest" target="_blank" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://www.****.com/details/<?php echo $value['id']; ?>&amp;media=<?php echo $image_urls; ?>&amp;description=<?php echo $value['description']; ?>" data-network="pinterest" style="display: block; left: 3px; top: 3px;"></a><a class="sb_network_button fa fa-facebook" target="_blank" href="//www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.****.com/details/<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" data-network="facebook" style="display: block; left: 3px; top: 3px;"></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div class="actions">
     <span id="changelike<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
  <span 
  <?php if($this->session->userdata('session_userId')==''){ ?> 
  onclick="alert('Login First');"
  <?php } else { 
  if($dataa == 0){ ?>
  onclick="return Favorite('<?php echo $this->session->userdata('session_userId'); ?>','<?php echo $value['id']; ?>',1);" 
  <?php } 
  else {
     ?> 
  onclick="return Favorite('<?php echo $this->session->userdata('session_userId'); ?>','<?php echo $value['id']; ?>',0);"  <?php } } ?> class="like-post <?php if($dataa == 0){ ?> <?php } else { ?> active <?php } ?>" >
   <span class="like-icon heart" ><div class="heart-animation-1 heart"></div><div class="heart-animation-2 heart"></div></span>
  </span>
  </span>
```

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Really unclear what you are after.

Comment: @ssBarBee when i back to that liked photo, it didn't re-liked again, so the problem is, when i back to a liked photo, that function reexcuted and liked the photo again, so i think i'm missing a condition